# Android chat server-client source or way to do it

Tags: java, android, chat

I need to do a simple 1 to 1 chat. I thought the only way to do it is:

Text from Client1

> Client1  ->  SERVER  -> Client2

Answer from Client2 2:

> Client2  ->  SERVER  ->  Client1

I found some source code, but I do not know how can I do on my server. Should I deploy it with tomcat or use a simple php class ?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) with [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) for a chat server. Websockets are better (faster, less resource consuming) than long polling.

You can also do it with PHP but I think it is not the best solution, because the HTTP protocol was not designed to allow `Server->Client` events. It was designed just to answer client requests.

Comment: thx for the clear answer, but i'm totally ignorant with web applications. the node.js's example has the .listen(1337, '127.0.0.1'); how can I use a public ip? I have to host a server and put it the andress there?

Comment: Node.js is installed on your server. Your Node.js app will just listen on a custom port of that server. You don't need to change that IP, as it means `localhost`.